# Writing code for destructor in side derived class in case of multiple inheritance with polymorphism increasing size of Derived class. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>
struct Base1
{
public:
    virtual void show()=0;
};
struct Base2
{
public:
    virtual void Display()=0;
};
class Derived:virtual public Base1,virtual public Base2
{
public:
    virtual void show(){}
    virtual void Display(){}

};
void main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout<<sizeof(Derived);
}
```

output is showing 12
but when i insert destructor of Dervied class i.e. following code

```
#include <iostream>
struct Base1
{
public:
    virtual void show()=0;
};
struct Base2
{
public:
    virtual void Display()=0;
};
class Derived:virtual public Base1,virtual public Base2
{
public:
    virtual void show(){}
    virtual void Display(){}
        ~Derived(){}


};
void main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout<<sizeof(Derived);
}
```

then it is showing 20 as output. why?

Comment: Not critical, but what compiler is that reproduced on?

Comment: @sharptooth : - whenever i am running the program it is showing same result..

Comment: i am working on visual vc++ 9.0

Answer (score 1):

1) Your base classes do not have virtual destructor.
2) main return int, not void

What you ask is implementation defined. Using g++ 4.3.0, I got the same size in both cases (8 bytes should be good result on a 32-bits PC).

EDIT

Under implementation defined, I meant it depends on how the virtual inheritance is implemented. Usually, the derived class contains pointers to base classes, but that't not necessary the case.

In the case of g++, to be able to get the address of every sub-object (pointer to a base class), the size of Derived should be 12 bytes (on a 32-bit machine), but because all classes are empty (i.e. without member variables), the compiler is free to optimize the size of empty base classes, and to reduce the size to 8 bytes (not 4 bytes, because it needs to be able to provide different address of both base classes).

Comment: If it is implementation defined, it should be documented somewhere in the gcc manual. Can you pull it out?

Comment: i have added virtual ~Base1() and virtual ~Base2() in respective class.but result is same i.e when ~Dervied() not present then 12 when i inserted then it showing 20.i am working on visual vc++ 9.0

Comment: @Chubsdad Having problems finding it in the gcc manual, but the edit explains how the inheritance is implemented in g++. The implementation should be similar for vc9, no?

Comment: @VJo:- Can u explain in terms of VC++ compiler.taking both the cases individually.

Comment: @Suri No, because I know very little about windows and VC++ compiler.

Comment: @VJo:i think you r talking about structure padding concept.but i think this concept is different from structure padding.but probably implementation of virtual concept is the reason.but how it is implemented is the question.

Comment: @Suri No. Structure padding is different. It would happen for example in this case struct A{ int a : 7; int b : 13;}; Now take a look at your example. I see no member variables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at the generated code, the first example has this memory layout:

```
| Derived::vtable |  Base1::vtable  |  Base2::vtable  |
```

The second has this layout:

```
| Derived::vtable |   00 00 00 00   |  Base1::vtable  |   00 00 00 00   |
|  Base2::vtable  |
```

What are the zeros I don't know. They are *not* padding, since padding is left uninitialized with `CCCCCCCC`. Maybe they are used as counters or flags when deleting the virtual subobjects and when you add the destructor these fields are added to the class. I failed in making them different from `00000000`.

Anyway, you can add this to your question: Why when I make the destructor `virtual` then the layout becomes

```
| Derived::vtable |   00 00 00 00   |  Base1::vtable  |   00 00 00 00   |
|  Base2::vtable  |     padding     |
```

(24 bytes)?